# Android ProgressBar inside ImageView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, progress-bar

I have an activity that fills a listview with data via an asynctask..additional i am loading a picture in the background...while the picture is loading, i would like to show a progressbar instead of a Default Icon in the imageview. I searched for any examples etc. in the internet but I couldnt find anything useful. I only found one Response which says that you have to make a framelayout with an imageview and a progressbar and Change the visibility during the loading process... I hoped there would be any other ways.. any idea how i can realize that?  is this possible generally?

Comment: No, there is no other way.  You need to have your imageview and your progressbar.  Start by imageview invisible and progressbar visible.  Keep updating progressbar while loading - when completed, set progressbar visibility to 'gone' and the imageview's visibility to 'visible'