# Android: Setting the progressbar inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I am trying to place a progress bar inside the listview so the image can load once it gets them from the facebook friend list. I declare the progress bar inside the XML layout. I implement the async method. I set the image invisible and in the post execute method I set it visible and the progress bar to gone. However, the progress bar remains on the view spinning and it does not go away.

My question is very similar to this question but no solution is provided.

[Android ProgressBar inside ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197038/android-progressbar-inside-imageview)

My code as follow in my custom ArrayAdaptor:

UPDATED:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textview;
    public CircularImageView image;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //REUSES THE VIEW

    if(convertView==null){

        // inflate the layout

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        viewHolder.image = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fb_friendpics);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

     ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

    holder.textview.setText(objectItem.itemName);
    holder.textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //call the execute cmd
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_fbpics);


    holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    new DownloadImageTask(holder, progressBar)
            .execute("https://graph.facebook.com/" + objectItem.itemId + "/picture?type=large");

    return convertView;

}


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public DownloadImageTask(ViewHolder holder, ProgressBar progressBar) {

        this.holder = holder;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if(result!=null ) {
            Log.d("IMAGE: " , "SET");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.image.setImageBitmap(result);
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }
}
```

Once I go to the screen it prints this many times when it should only print twice since I only have to contacts.

```
09-03 19:53:21.587  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.632  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.668  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.718  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.773  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.829  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.891  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:21.947  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.035  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.086  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.153  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.228  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.389  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.675  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:22.844  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:23.028  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:23.230  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:23.432  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:23.769  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:23.954  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:24.139  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:24.324  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET 
09-03 19:53:24.677  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:24.863  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.089  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.393  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.609  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.674  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.754  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.805  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.872  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.923  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:25.973  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:26.024  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
09-03 19:53:26.091  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.142  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET 
 09-03 19:53:26.211  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.277  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.328  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.395  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.480  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.548  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.633  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.681  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.748  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.799  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.849  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET 
 09-03 19:53:26.900  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:26.969  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:27.020  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:27.085  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:27.153  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:27.220  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
 09-03 19:53:27.271  30339-30339/com.voiceup.voiceup D/IMAGE:﹕ SET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you are referencing a `progressbar` that was declared as a field in the outer class of DownloadTask. You don't have direct access to the `progressbar` in Adapter.getView().

Aside from that, I would make two recommendations:

1. I highly recommend you pickup a 3rd party image loading library for this. For example, take a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), and [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco).
2. Use view recycling in your adapter. I can see that you're not using any sort of recycling. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70), and this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think I need to use NotifyDataSetChanged()? To Implement the View Recycling is a great idea to improve performance. There was no code provided to do this. Am I suppose to use the view holder for this?

Comment: NotifyDataSetChanged should be called when you alter your underlying data. For example, if you add ore remove items from your Adapter. However, the default ArrayAdapter implementation will automatically call NotifyDataSetChanged for you when you use ArrayAdapter.add, ArrayAdapter.remove, etc, so there's no need to call it explicitly.

Comment: I am only displaying the Facebook friend list on the list view. So nothing from the data will be removed or added. So I don't think I will need to use NotifyDataSetChanged(). For View Recycling do you have any documentation for that?

Comment: Just take a look at the 2 links I sent in my answer, that should get you started.

Comment: @WindsuferOak I updated the code above. I was able to use the view holder which improved the performance of the list view. I will look into Picasso. I would like to know if you can assist me on another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361116/android-how-to-setup-a-connection-between-two-mobile-devcies-wi-fi-or-network